# Multiple Auth Handlers / Forwarding

Tags: asp.net-core

Can anyone explain in simple terms what the 'forwarding' concept means in AspNetCore authentictation ? In the source code, comments on AuthenticationSchemeOptions class explain that the ForwardAuthenticate property is "If set, this specifies the target scheme that this scheme should forward AuthenticateAsync calls to"... What exactly does that mean ? In what secnario would this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L182), you could find, it just remove the previous scheme and use the Forward scheme to authenticate the user.

```
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scheme">The scheme to forward. One of ForwardAuthenticate, ForwardChallenge, ForwardForbid, ForwardSignIn, or ForwardSignOut.</param>
/// <returns>The forwarded scheme or <see langword="null"/>.</returns>
protected virtual string? ResolveTarget(string? scheme)
{
    var target = scheme ?? Options.ForwardDefaultSelector?.Invoke(Context) ?? Options.ForwardDefault;

    // Prevent self targetting
    return string.Equals(target, Scheme.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal)
        ? null
        : target;
}

/// <inheritdoc />
public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync()
{
    var target = ResolveTarget(Options.ForwardAuthenticate);
    if (target != null)
    {
        return await Context.AuthenticateAsync(target);
    }

    // Calling Authenticate more than once should always return the original value.
    var result = await HandleAuthenticateOnceAsync() ?? AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
    if (result.Failure == null)
    {
        var ticket = result.Ticket;
        if (ticket?.Principal != null)
        {
            Logger.AuthenticationSchemeAuthenticated(Scheme.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.AuthenticationSchemeNotAuthenticated(Scheme.Name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.AuthenticationSchemeNotAuthenticatedWithFailure(Scheme.Name, result.Failure.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The usage for this is, if one of the old existing scheme is should be replaced by a new one, by using this option could avoid a lot of code changing.